# Angular router stop working after importing ReactiveFormsModule

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create reactive form in Angular.

This is my login form.

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username" 
    [formControl]="loginForm.controls['username']" />

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Password</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Password" placeholder="Password" 
      [formControl]="loginForm.controls['password']" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I see the console, Then I found a error.

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

Then I imported `ReactiveFormsModule` in my main module and also in `login.component.ts` file. But now It's showing me another error.

Part of app.module.ts

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    routing.ngModule
  ]
```

And Part of file login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl,ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
```

> No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!

When I click on error, It take me to my `app.component.html` page at `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

But When I remove `ReactiveFormsModule` from my main module the this is gone.

Errors in console.

[image]

[image]

This my project on [GIT](https://github.com/Amit1150/AngularApp/tree/master/src/app)

Comment: What does "the this is gone" mean exactly? Is above form part of the main module?

Comment: If you're using reactive `form` in child module then child module should import `ReactiveFormsModule` in specifically in child module.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: No. I have separate component for login page . it's `login.component.html`

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. Is the separate component in a separate module?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: yes. `Gone' Means when I remove `ReactiveFormsModule` from module Then above error is gone, But previous error apears i.e `Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.`

Comment: Then you need to add `ReactiveFormsModule` to `imports: []` of this module.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: After importing `ReactiveFormsModule`, it throwing me error `No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!`

Comment: @PankajParkar: I've imported in my child module as well. but It's throwing me this error `No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!`  I have added my project link in question. Please check it.

Comment: @AmitKumar We do not need export `ReactiveFormsModule` and import `ReactiveFormsModule` in login component also.

Comment: @ThienHoang: I tried it . I removed from login module, and remove export code. But it's not working

Comment: Please remove `ReactiveFormsModule` in login.component.ts, I still see it in your GIT

Comment: @AmitKumar I see everything is ok now, can you check again and give us information in case it still throw errors ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147052/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-thien-hoang).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: If you found solution, Then please help me

Answer (score 1):

You might need to 'import' the name of your router. ie.

```
`export const routerConfig: Route[] = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/gifts', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'gifts', component: GiftsComponent },
];`
```

Would be:

```
`RouterModule.forRoot(routerConfig),`
```

So you need to add the `routerConfig` or whatever you assigned it as, to your imports.

Something like this:

```
`@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routerConfig), // ADD HERE
    ], ...
```

`